# How can I select and hightlight a row in a Table in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I am new to Codename One, and I am new to asking questions on Stack Overflow.  I think both are awesome!

I have a question about the Table class in Codename One. I searched the web, Stack Overflow, API, everything, and can't find a good answer.

I would like to be able to select a row and highlight it so I could subsequently perform operations on the data in it. I have gotten it to work by overriding the `createCell` method and making all the cells buttons, but this is not an acceptable approach.  The problem is because the table has to be rebuilt every time the user 'clicks' a cell.

When the table contains more rows than can be displayed, and the table is rebuilt, the table jumps back to the beginning of the table.  The user then has to scroll back down to the selected row if s/he wants to see it.  Having the table jump around like that is unacceptable.

Also, I might want to use other controls in the table. I know there is a `table.getSelectedRow()`, so it is possible that I am missing something. Also, I would like to know how to programmatically select a row.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I will use is the following:

1. For a single selection, a radio button in the first column.
2. For a multiple selection, a check box in the first column.

I am still curious what getSelectedRow() in the com.codename1.ui.table.Table class is for.

I hope this helps someone else in their GUI design.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the sample from the javadocs for `Table`. The one minor hack I did was `setModel(getModel())` to trigger a refresh of the table manually:

```
Form hi = new Form("Table", new BorderLayout());
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"}, new Object[][] {
    {"Row 1", "Row A", "Row X"},
    {"Row 2", "Row B can now stretch", null},
    {"Row 3", "Row C", "Row Z"},
    {"Row 4", "Row D", "Row K"},
    }) {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return col != 0;
        }
    };
Table table = new Table(model) {
    private int selectedRow = -1;
    @Override
    protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) { 
        Component cell;
        if(row < 0) {
            cell = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
        } else {
            cell = new Button(value.toString());
            cell.setUIID("TableCell");
            ((Button)cell).addActionListener(e -> {
                selectedRow = row;
                setModel(getModel());
            });
        }
        if(selectedRow > -1 && selectedRow == row) { 
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(100);
        } 
        return cell;
    }

    @Override
    protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
        TableLayout.Constraint con =  super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
        if(row == 1 && column == 1) {
            con.setHorizontalSpan(2);
        }
        con.setWidthPercentage(33);
        return con;
    }
};
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, table);
hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I came up with this same solution after doing research on the topic and before asking the question.  However, it does not meet all of my requirements.  I did come up with an alternative which I will post as an answer.  Thanks again for your help.